# Eurostat geospatial data NUTS-3 download for mapping

Tags: r, maps, gis, bubble-chart, choropleth

I am trying to download the geospatial data for NUTS-3 regions from the Eurostat but at the time of execute the code, I got the error of "unused argument for NUTS-3. Any way to solve it? Thanks in advance for your time. I post the code with the packages

```
library(eurostat)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

# download eurostat data of population counts by NUTS-3 region

euro_pop <- get_eurostat('demo_r_pjanaggr3', stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
   filter(sex == 'T', str_length(geo) == 5, age == 'TOTAL') # NUTS-3

# download geospatial data for NUTS-3 regions

euro_nuts3_sf <- get_eurostat_geospatial(output_class = 'sf', 
   resolution ='60', nuts_level = 3) %>%
   st_transform(crs = 3035)

Error in get_eurostat_geospatial(output_class = "sf", resolution = "60",  : 
unused argument (nuts_level = 3)
```

Comment: Not sure if you got this solved yet, but according to the documentation for the `eurostat` package the `3` in `nuts_level` should be in quotes.

Comment: It works, it works! Thanks!